# get list from based on another list

Tags: c#

I asked this question earlier, but I over simplified it, and I still don't know how to do it in a better way than I'm doing (for).

I got two lists.

One, a list of facebook friends, a simple object, consider facebook.id the only property.

Second, a list of users, it's a more complex object, because each user gets a lists of providers inside (facebook, twitter, etc), but the providers list can be null, and if not null, not necessarily the provider is a facebook one. So:

```
public class EFacebook
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class EUser
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Nullable
    /// </summary>
    public List<EProvider> EProviders { get; set; }
}

public class EProvider
{
    public enum EnumProviderType
    {
        Facebook = 2,
        Twitter = 3
    }
    public EnumProviderType ProviderType { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is to filter the facebook list to get all the facebook friends that are users and get all the facebook friends that are not users.

Comment: What part did you not understand in the answers to the previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096826/get-elements-from-list-based-on-another-list

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `List<EFacebook> fbList` is the first list and `List<EUser> usersList` is the second list.
You can do something like this:

`fbList.Where(x=>usersList.Select(x=>x.Id).Contains(x.Id))` ==> this will return the list of facebook entities that are users.
The second list is the difference between this fbList and this one.

Let me know if I understood the question correctly!

Tamash

Comment: the equivalence between a EUser and a EFacebook is not in user.Id and facebook.Id, it is between user.EProvider<of type facebook>.Id and facebook.Id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this:

```
List<EFacebook> listEFacebookFriends = new List<EFacebook>();
List<EUser> listEUsers = new List<EUser>();
```

Then you can get a list of all Facebook friends that are users here:

```
var listEUsersOnFacebook = from user in listEUsers
    let fbProviders =
    from provider in user.EProviders
    where provider.ProviderType == EProvider.EnumProviderType.Facebook
    select provider.Id
    where fbProviders.Count() > 0
    select user.Id;

// this next call will get facebook friends that are users
var friendsOnFacebook = listEFacebookFriends.Where(x => 
                                listEUsersOnFacebook.Contains(x.Id));
```

And here you can get your Facebook friends that are NOT users:

```
var listEUsersNotOnFacebook = from user in listEUsers
    let fbProviders =
    from provider in user.EProviders
    where provider.ProviderType == EProvider.EnumProviderType.Facebook
    select provider.Id
    where fbProviders.Count() == 0
    select user.Id;

// this call will get facebook friends that are not users 
var friendsNotOnFacebook = listEFacebookFriends.Where(x => 
                            listEUsersNotOnFacebook.Contains(x.Id));
```

Comment: the equivalence between a EUser and a EFacebook is not in user.Id and facebook.Id, it is between user.EProvider<of type facebook>.Id and facebook.Id.